# Having One context for all repositories causing errors

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm trying to share my DBcontext between all my repositories,

so this is my `workflowContext`

```
public class WorkflowContext : DbContext {
    public WorkflowContext()
        : base("name=WorkflowContext") {
    }

    public DbSet<Instance> Instances { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the baseRepo

```
public class WorkFlowBaseRepo {
    protected static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    internal WorkflowContext Db;

    public WorkFlowBaseRepo() {
        Db = new WorkflowContext();
    }

    internal void SetState(object instance, EntityState state) {
        Log.DebugFormat("setting {0} state", ObjectContext.GetObjectType(instance.GetType()));
        try {
            if (Db.Entry(instance).State != EntityState.Added) {
                Db.Entry(instance).State = state;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.Error("Error setting state", e);
        }
    }

    internal int SaveChanges() {
        Log.DebugFormat("Saving changes");
        try {
            return Db.SaveChanges();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.Error("Error Saving", e);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    internal void Dispose() {
        try {
            Db.Dispose();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.Error("Error disposing", e);
        }
    }
}
```

and then repo's inherit from the `WorkflowBaseRepo`, this is an example of a repo:

```
public class InstanceRepo : WorkFlowBaseRepo {
    private readonly DocumentRepo _documentRepo;
    private readonly TaskRepo _taskRepo;
    private readonly WorkflowRepo _workflowRepo;
    private readonly MailService _mailService;
    private readonly QService _qService;
    private readonly OService _oService;
    public InstanceRepo() {
        _workflowRepo = new WorkflowRepo();
        _mailService = new MailService();
        _documentRepo = new DocumentRepo();
        _taskRepo = new TaskRepo();
        _oService = new OService();
        _qService = new QService();
    }

    internal List<Instance> GetAll() {
        Log.DebugFormat("Getting all Instances");
        try {
            return Db.Instances.ToList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.Error("Error getting all instance", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    internal Instance GetById(int id) {
        Log.DebugFormat("Getting instance {0}", id);
        try {
            var instance = Db.Instances.Find(id);


            var docid = instance.Document != null ? instance.Document.Id : -1;
            instance.Document = _documentRepo.GetByDocumentId(instance.ObjectId);

            if (instance.Document.Id != docid) {
                Db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return instance;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.Error("Error finding instance", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    internal Instance AddInstance(InstancePostDto instance) {
        // code 
    }

    internal Instance RemoveInstance(Instance instance) {
        Log.DebugFormat("Removing Instance {0}", instance.Id);
        try {
            return Db.Instances.Remove(instance);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.Error("Error removing instance", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    internal void SetState(Instance instance, EntityState state) {
        try {
            base.SetState(instance, state);
            instance.UdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.Error("Error", e);
        }
    }

    internal bool InstanceExists(int id) {
        try {
            return Db.Instances.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.Error("Error", e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

but now I'm getting the following errors when updating `The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.`

Any idea why this is happening? and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You are not sharing your `DbContext` among your repositories, each is getting a new instance of it from the base class's constructor:

```
public WorkFlowBaseRepo() {
    Db = new WorkflowContext();
}
```

This is why you are seeing the exception that related objects are attached to different instances of the context. Your `InstanceRepo` actually has 7 different instances of `WorkflowContext`.

The best way to solve this is to use a Dependency Injection container (also known as an Inversion of Control container) like SimpleInjector, StructureMap, Ninject, Autofac, Castle Windsor... there are other choices as well. Use one of these to enable constructor injection, then register your DbContext instance as a scoped dependency. That way you would get one of those per scoped operation in your application (for example in a web application, a "scope" would mean a single request).

Something like this (pseudo code)

```
var container = new Container();
container.RegisterScoped<WorkflowContext>(x => new WorkflowContext());
container.Verify();
```

---

```
public class WorkFlowBaseRepo {

    internal WorkflowContext Db;

    public WorkFlowBaseRepo(WorkflowContext db) {
        Db = db;
    }
```

Then, your container would make sure all repos received the same referential instance of the `WorkflowContext` dependency within the same scope.

Note how I made the `DbContext` a constructor argument. You could probably get away with something like this if you **really** have an aversion to IoC:

```
public InstanceRepo(WorkflowContext db) {
    Db = db ?? new WorkflowContext();
    _workflowRepo = new WorkflowRepo(Db);
    _mailService = new MailService(Db);
    _documentRepo = new DocumentRepo(Db);
    _taskRepo = new TaskRepo(Db);
    _oService = new OService(Db);
    _qService = new QService(Db);
}
```

With the above, your `InstanceRepo` is sharing its instance of `DbContext` with all of the other repos. But note that here, we are still "constructor injecting" a dependency, even if there is no IoC container.

Comment: Hmm, would something like this work ?
 internal WorkflowContext Db {
   get { return _db ?? (_db = new WorkflowContext()); }
  }

Comment: @Kiwi no, because each instance of the repo would still have a null `_db` and hence would still create a new one. Putting something in the constructor of a base class does not "share" it across all instances. You need `static` members to do that. But you will run into different problems if you defined your `DbContext` as `static`.

Comment: would moving the dbcontext to the repo's itself via using resolve this? I don't really want to add DIC's

Comment: @Kiwi no, you would have the same problem.